# Function Overriding in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have created `BaseClassviewController` and all my controllers are derived from this controller. I am doing the following steps:

1. Set custom delegate in `BaseClassViewController`.
2. Implement all function of protocol in `BaseClassViewController`.
3. Then I am pushing `HomeController` derived from `BaseClassViewController`.
4. Again I am pushing `DetailController` also derived from `BaseClassViewController`.

Now when delegate function is called I should get control in `DetailController` but I am getting control in `HomeController`.

So my question is why its not calling top controller at navigation i.e `DetailController` and is it possible to call delegate functions in both controllers?

P.S I am overriding delegate functions in all child controllers.

**EDIT:** After reading answers and comments I think I have not been clear that much so adding following code snippet.

In Helper Class:

```
@objc protocol SampleDelegate: class
{
    @objc optional func shouldCallDelegateMethod()
}

class SampleHelper: NSObject
{
    var sampleDelegate:SampleDelegate!
    static var sharedInstance = SampleHelper()

   //It is triggered 
   func triggerDelegateMethod()
   {
     sampleDelegate!.shouldCallDelegateMethod()
   }

   func apiCall()
   {
      let urlString = URL(string: "https://google.com")
      if let url = urlString {
      let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
      if error != nil {
         print(error)
      } else {
      if let usableData = data {
           self. triggerDelegateMethod()
           }
         }
       }
       task.resume()
     }
   }
}
```

In BaseClass

```
class BaseClassViewController: UIViewController,SampleDelegate{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
       SampleHelper.sharedInstance.delegate = self;
    }

    func shouldCallDelegateMethod()
    {
        //Override
    }


}
```

In HomeController i.e 1st controller to be pushed

```
class HomeViewController: BaseClassViewController{

        override func shouldCallDelegateMethod()
        {
            //
        }
}
```

In DetailController i.e 2nd controller is pushed after HomeController from HomeController.

```
class DetailViewController: BaseClassViewController{
        override func viewDidLoad()
        {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           SampleHelper.sharedInstance.apiCall()
        }
        override func shouldCallDelegateMethod()
        {
            //
        }
}
```

Now my question is when delegate is triggered from helper class it calls `shouldCallDelegateMethod` in `HomeViewController` but not in `DetailViewController`. But `DetailViewController` is at top of navigation array.

Also is there any possibility I can trigger same function in both controller at a time with delegate only?

Comment: Please share your code snippet of declaring and overriding delegates.

Comment: Its pretty big codebase to show here in constructive way. But I think I have explained it in decent way conceptually..

Comment: @Aamir If you need anything in specific let me know I can explain.

Comment: I would commented but I can't now (rep below 50). Are you calling your delegate method on `DetailController`. You may be calling it on your `HomeController`. Have you assigned your `DetailController` delegate? Also check if you are calling your delegate of `DetailController` before it is being pushed. I wouldn't try to call both delegates. Are you trying to pass data down the viewcontroller hierarchy?

Comment: Well I am assigning delegate in BaseClassViewController and all controllers are subclass of BaseViewController.. And I am conformin protocol in BaseClassViewCOntroller and then overriding in child controllers..

Comment: It is very unclear what you mean here. What is a "custom delegate?" (You mean you've created your own delegate protocol?) What is calling this delegate function? Why do you believe it "should get control" (I'm not sure what that means) in `DetailController`? What do you believe should be calling "top controller at navigation?" How these classes inherit is almost certainly irrelevant here. You've likely wired things up incorrectly. It's not clear what you mean by "pushing." Are you using a storyboard segue, or directly presenting? Why is it tagged both ObjC and Swift? Is it both?

Comment: @Aamir Check the code snippet

Comment: @LightS33k3r Check the code snippet

Comment: @RobNapier Half of the questions I think is now answered with my edit. I am using normal pushviewController by code. Its is tagged both objc and Swift because it is conceptual question that is valid for both language.

Comment: Using delegates with singletons is an antipattern. Use completion callbacks with singletons otherwise you will keep running into problems.

Answer (score 0):

In `BaseClassviewController` you should have a `delegate` variable/property.

In `HomeController` and `DetailController` you need to set that `delegate` variable/property to `self` if you want that class to be listening to the delegate callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2**

After you posted your code, i realize that you have used the singleton class for delegation.

**Delegates** allows an object to send a message to another object.

**Answer** for your query is "No". You can not trigger same function in both controller at a time with delegate.

If you really want to listen an event in both class at a time, i would suggest you to use `NSNotificationCenter` instead of delegate.

Comment: Write SampleHelper.sharedInstance.delegate = self; in viewWillappear method of homeVC and DetailVC.

Comment: Then it beats the purpose of subclassing and also I have overriden the methods in all child class..

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you are using delegate with a singleton.

Setting the delegate in `viewWillAppear` is not a good solution either. In short, when view controllers are being shown and hidden, the delegate on your singleton will changed all the time.

Don't use delegates with singletons. Use a completion callback. Otherwise you will keep running into problems.

```
func apiCall(onCompletion: (() -> Void)?) {
    let urlString = URL(string: "https://google.com")
    if let url = urlString {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else if let usableData = data {
                onCompletion?()
            }
        }

        task.resume()
     }
}
```

called as

```
SampleHelper.apiCall {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I agree with your point but still it doesnt answer my question why it did not call func in Detail than in Home Controller.

Comment: Also if you can elaborate little bit to address your point in detail will be helpful..

Comment: But this delegate can be called from multiple places in same class.. Like for example createGroup for XMPP.. in that case I can get API response as well to inform that group has been created and as well I can receive message through XMPP.. So I have to update controllers to update their UI..

Comment: @KrishnaKumar Both `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` are not very good places to register anything. You would have to use `viewDidAppear` *everywhere*. Still that architecture would be fundamentally broken. Why do you even use `sharedInstance`? Why don't you let every controller to create its own helper? Then your delegates will work correctly.

Comment: As there is another layer named Communicator which interacts with all helper classes and controllers communicate with communicator only. Also I am setting delegate to Baseviewcontroller and then overriding delegate methods in all child controllers. I got your point that I should not set delegate in view delegates..

Answer (score -1):

Thats not the correct way to achieve this. I think proper way to set delegate only in respective `UIViewController` rather than implementing that protocol on `BaseViewController` and then overriding in child classes. So your implementation should be like.

In HomeViewController

```
class HomeViewController: BaseClassViewController {

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    SampleHelper.sharedInstance.delegate = self;
  }

  func shouldCallDelegateMethod() {
    // Provide implementation
  }

}
```

In DetailViewController

```
class DetailViewController: BaseClassViewController {

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    SampleHelper.sharedInstance.delegate = self;
  }

  func shouldCallDelegateMethod() {
    // Provide implementation
  }

}
```

Using this imeplementation you will be having only **one-to-one** communication design pattern, ensuring right `UIViewController` to be called.

Comment: Because we are putting another level of indirection by implementing protocol in `BaseViewController`, we should implement this directly in respective ViewController.

Comment: But I need to implement it in different contollers. And I am not able to get why it is adding level of indirection as delegate is always assigned to BaseClassViewController and we are just overriding those functions..

Comment: Do you want one-to-many delegation pattern? If so, then you need to use NSNotifications.

Comment: I was kind of avoiding that.. But still I am unclear why just overriding function not working in this case. As far as delegate is concerned its getting called.. But overriding is creating problem as it is working in one controller but not on other at a time..